# PhpStorm CaseSensitive autocomplete solution

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, case-sensitive

I used to use NetBeans for my PHP developments but I'm trying to use PhpStorm instead recently. There is that annoying Case Sensitive Auto Complete of PhpStorm I can't solve. What can I do?

```
case:   class CapitalClass { ...
```

It wont work when I try to type with small `c` at using this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion`

Choose more suitable option for `Case sensitive completion` setting

[image]